# Can't load image in Blender 2.79b

Tags: texturing

I'm trying to get an image loaded to Blender 2.79b, but sadly, it will refuse to load. It will just say "Can't Load Image". Please help me fix this problem!

Comment: A little more info might be helpful.... What kind of image? What size?

Comment: S3E11_Paperfan.png. It's a 1080p image.